# Is it possible for AWS CDK to create a secret with a blank or placeholder value?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

I'm connecting my CodePipeline to Github, so I added this lines:

```ts
CodePipelineSource.gitHub("username/repo", "main", {
   authentication: cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager("github-token")
})
```

and when I run `cdk deploy`, it fails expectedly with:

```
Pipeline/Pipeline (Pipeline9850B417) Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret. (Service: AWSSecretsManager; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: eaa59d67-bb64-472c-abc4-9d4896c09d7e; Proxy: null)
```

Is it possible for CDK to create the secret, with a **blank or placeholder value**, so that it would still fail with some sort of access denied, but then I can go to the AWS console and just fill in the value.

Clarification: I'm not expecting CDK to create an OAuth token. What I wanted to achieve is run `cdk deploy`, have it fail, go to Secrets Manager and find the secret with a placeholder value, enter the value, run `cdk deploy` again, and succeed that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a secret just like any other resource.

```ts
const secret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, 'Secret');
```

It will populate it with a generated placeholder value. You can also grant some role read/write access to the secret with `secret.grantRead(role);`

Refer to the documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_secretsmanager.Secret.html

You also need to tell the CDK that your pipeline depends on the secret with
[`my_pipeline.node.addDependency(secret);`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/constructs.Node.html#addwbrdependencydeps)

Comment: This answers the question in the title very well. But it won't solve the poster's problem. The CDK `pipeline`[synth action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cdk_pipeline.html#cdk_pipeline_define) will fail without a valid github token as the secret value.  CDK won't be able to create the github webhook and the stack deploy will fail if a generated secret is used.

Comment: Sure, it'll fail, but why is that an issue? You can deploy the stacks, populate the secret, and rerun the pipeline.

Comment: I'm not expecting the pipeline to be able to create the github token. But when I tried something like that, it didn't work. I'll try again.

Comment: @pupeno declaring an explicit dependency between the resources is key here.

Comment: Yes, that was something I was missing.

Comment: @gshpychka having to deploy a stack twice because of this points to an engineering problem. You shouldn't expect it to fail the first time, it should work every time. In this case, the stack _should_ fail if the secret wasn't manually set before the stack was deployed.

Comment: @JoshM. the secret may be provisioned in a separate stack, which would be deployed first, the secret populated, and then the rest of the stacks can be deployed.

Comment: @gshpychka understood but it still feels like a workaround -- at least in some cases.

Comment: @JoshM. populating the secret has to be decoupled from the rest of the infrastructure, so I don't see any real alternatives.

Comment: In a single stack you could create the secret, then add a condition (CfnCondition) to the dependent constructs.  The condition would be built by reading the value of the secret and checking if the secret value is not your defined default value.  This still requires the stack to be deployed twice as the dependent constructs won't be deployed until a non-default value is set in the secret.  Fyi, the condition prop lives on the L1 construct.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit tricky. Long story short, we must create the secret outside the pipeline stack.

We can create a generated [Secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_secretsmanager.Secret.html#secretvalue) with the CDK (and get its `secretValue: SecretValue`). But, as you discovered, the challenge is safely updating the secret with the actual github token value. Setting `mySecret.secretValue` in the synth action and deferring the actual token value update won't work. The CDK-generated secret value will cause the pipeline stack deploy to fail with an `Invalid credentials` error.

So how can we create the secret, set its value and provide it to the synth action? There are several options.  Each involves constructing the secret outside the pipeline stack<sup>1</sup>:

1. **Create the secret manually in the AWS Console** The github token is a cross-app resource, likely to be reused in multiple CDK apps. Rather than tying
   it to a specific app, create it manually in the console. Next, in your pipeline stack, use [SecretValue's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#secrets)`cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager('github-token')` static method in the app to get a reference to the secret.<sup>2</sup>
2. **Create the secret in a new, separate CDK app** Create cross-app resources like secrets and IAM users in a separate "shared" CDK app. Deploy the app, update
   the github-token value to the actual token value, then read in its value in your app.<sup>2</sup>
3. **Create the secret in a separate stack in your app** Deploy the app. The secret-stack will deploy but the pipeline stack will fail (because the secret is a CDK-generated one). Update the token value in the console, redeploy your app. Second time around, the pipeline will find the valid token and deploy OK.

---

(1) Advanced, single-stack option: Pass a deploy-time parameter with the token value to a custom resource that calls the [PutSecretValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-secrets-manager/classes/putsecretvaluecommand.html) API. Complex, smells of overengineering.

(2) Secrets have a fixed cost of $0.50/month, so it may be worthwhile to share the github-token secret across multiple apps.

Comment: This answer is so comprehensive and provide options and pros and cons. Combined with the pipeline dependency from @gshpychka below, it will be perfect.